# SQL Query + special characters ä, ö, ü, ø etc

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, collation

I'm wrapping my head around a problem for the last couple of days and need some tips on how to solve the problem.

I have a sql query which looks like this

```
    mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $sql_first = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `usermeta` WHERE `meta_value` = '".$value."'
```

It works fine if $value isn't containing characters like `ä ü ö ø`

The collation of the database is `utf8_general_ci`

I tried various combinations with the php `conv()` function, but can't get it to work.

I guess I have to convert `$value` to UTF-8 - is this going in the right direction?

Comment: It does not work even without special characters: imagine this `$value`: `"Robert';drop table usermeta; --"`. **Do not try it, just imagine what would happen.** This is a [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) example, commonly known as SQL Interjection attack.

Comment: SQL *interjection* attack: *Oh shit!* :-)

Comment: You should tag your question with `sql-injection`. That way we'll also know you're using PHP. </troll>

Comment: But I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string($value);` right before it - which should make a sql-injection _almost_ impossible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements, and the database driver will do everything for you, and you won't be subject to SQL injection attacks as a bonus.

See http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: It is still not working, is this how you would use the bind function? `$stmt->bind_param("s", $value);`

Answer (score 0):

I would say to try the `utf8_unicode_ci`  collation

From [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748#msg-188748) link:

Main differences are:

1. utf8_unicode_ci supports so called expansions and ligatures, for example: 
   German letter ß (U+00DF LETTER SHARP S) is sorted near "ss" 
   Letter Œ (U+0152 LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE) is sorted near "OE".

utf8_general_ci does not support expansions/ligatures, it sorts 
all these letters as single characters, and sometimes in a wrong order.

1. utf8_unicode_ci is *generally* more accurate for all scripts. 
   For example, on Cyrillic block: 
   utf8_unicode_ci is fine for all these languages: 
   Russian, Bulgarian, Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, and Ukrainian. 
   While utf8_general_ci is fine only for Russian and Bulgarian subset of Cyrillic. 
   Extra letters used in Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, and Ukrainian 
   are sorted not well.

The disadvantage of utf8_unicode_ci is that it is a little bit 
slower than utf8_general_ci.

So when you need better sorting order - use utf8_unicode_ci, 
and when you utterly interested in performance - use utf8_general_ci.

Comment: You should actually use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. UTF8 in SQL isn't actually UTF8. See [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/2415524).