# Special characters into MySQL table not displaying properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using `CodeIgniter` to build my queries and one of the fields that I am importing is something like:

```
textØ=125mm
```

The insert/update is always successful but it is appearing in the table as:

```
text??=125mm
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Check the character set of your mySQL table/database

Comment: Please read here, it's been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563439/sql-query-special-characters-a-o-u-o-etc

Comment: check that 1) db table is in utf8, 2) db connection is utf8, 3) contents you are inserting is utf8 (web page encoding, check from browser Tools->Encoding)

Comment: CSV file contents is UTF8? Excel doesnt handle CSV files as utf8 by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `database.php` config file and make sure it has the value :

```
$db['development']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['development']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in MySQL change the Collation of database to

> utf8_general_ci

. And yes, Be sure to check the character encoding of your HTML Page. i.e, use a META TAG at the head part

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: My collation is already set to utf8_general_ci and there is no html involved as the data is coming from a CSV file.

Comment: As mentioned in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563439/sql-query-special-characters-a-o-u-o-etc) You should probably change the Collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in controller or view:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```